# Why does my loop gone infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, infinite-loop, prime-factoring

I am writing a function that will find prime factors of a number.
In that function, it has got two loops. One for finding factors, another for finding prime factors from the first loop. The second loop has gone infinite, I haven't spotted anywhere in the loop that could make it infinite. Where did I miss?

```
function findPrimeFactors(num)
{
 var factors = [];
 var primeFactors = [];
 var currIndex = 0;
 var initFactorsLen;
 var currCompose;
 for (i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
 {
  if (num % i == 0)
  {
   factors.push(i);
  }
 }
 var initFactorsLen = factors.length;
 for (i = 0; i <= initFactorsLen; ++i) 
 {
 //This is infinite loop
  console.log("i is " + i + " and factors are " + factors);
  currCompose = factors[i];
  var primeTest = isPrime(currCompose); 
  if (primeTest == true)
  {
   primeFactors.push(currCompose);
  }
 }
 return primeFactors;
}

function isPrime(num)
{
 var sqrtNum = Math.sqrt(num);
 var ceiledNum = Math.ceil(sqrtNum);
 if (num == 1 || num == 0)
 {
  return false;
 }
 else if (num == 2)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  for (i = 2; i <= ceiledNum; ++i)
  {
   if (num % i == 0 && i != num)
   {
    return false;
   }
  }
  return true;
 }
}
```

I've also notice that sometimes it doesn't gone infinite, but it returns only one prime number although it has 2. (Try `findPrimeFactors(143)`)

Thanks,

Comment: Because you are using [global variables all over your code](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), and `isPrime` does modify your loop counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `i` loop variable is global, so both functions share the same values for `i`.

Initialize *and declare* it with `var`, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= initFactorsLen; ++i)
```

An alternative to declaring it within the loop statement is to declare it with your other variables.  Note that you can declare all your variables in a comma-separated list, like this:

```
var factors = [],
    primeFactors = [],
    currIndex = 0,
    initFactorsLen,
    currCompose,
    i;
```

Also note that you don't need to explicitly check for truthness.  This:

```
var primeTest = isPrime(currCompose); 
if (primeTest == true) {
  primeFactors.push(currCompose);
}
```

… is equivalent to this:

```
var primeTest = isPrime(currCompose); 
if (primeTest) {
  primeFactors.push(currCompose);
}
```

… or more simply:

```
if (isPrime(currCompose)) {
  primeFactors.push(currCompose);
}
```

Comment: Does (!primeTest) means that` isPrime(currCompose)` return false?

Comment: Given `var primeTest = isPrime(currCompose);`, if `isPrime(currCompose)` is false, then `primeTest` would be false, and `!primeTest` would be true.

Comment: So, !primeTest will return opposite of the real value?

Comment: `!` negates an expression.  So `!true` is false, and `!false` is true.

Comment: Thanks, I have been searching that for a week. But no where can tell me :D

Comment: MDN has a good reference of JavaScript operators.  `!` is one of the logical operators:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with javascript... are you sure your 'i' is not shared by your loop in your two functions. What happens if you use 'k' as index in the function 'isprime'?

Never mind, it was solved 10 minutes ago

Comment: Using a different global index variable would solve the problem, but it's better to use local variables only to help prevent side effects like this.